# The .replace() method does change the string in place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply try to use the `.replace()` method. And it does not work.

HTML:

```
<div class="try"> </div>
```

JS:

```
var valr='r';
valr.replace('r', 't');
$('.try').prepend('<div> ' + valr + '</div>');
```

Result: I get 'r', while I would like to get 't'

Any idea on why it doesn't work?

Comment: From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) _This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string._

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`replace()` (a JavaScript function, not jQuery) returns a string, try this :

```
var valr='r';
valr = valr.replace('r', 't');
$('.try').prepend('<div> '+valr+'</div>');
```

[Docs for `.replace()` are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: @JulietteDupuis no probs - check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference) when you have issues like this - all JavaScript functions are documented there

Answer (score 7):

You need to save the variable after it has been replaced

```
valr = valr.replace('r','t');
```

Answer (score 5):

First off `replace` is not a jQuery method - it's plain javascript. Second, it returns a new instance of the string so you need:

```
valr = valr.replace('r', 't');
```